# How Disable unit testing in PhpStorm

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm, xdebug

I am having a issue in PhpStorm when I try to debug my php application. When click in debug button it automatically run the PHPUnit test suite of my project.

In my case I just want to debug the application through Xdebug.

Please, someone do know how disable the unit testing in PHPUnit?

Comment: So .. you have messed up with your project .. and instead of "fixing" it you want to disable other whole functionality instead? Interesting approach... Screenshots of your IDE setup please. Most likely you just need to delete unwanted or switch to another Run/Debug Configuration and that would be it.